# How to bring components of columns vertically aligned

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-grid

I have to vertically align the elements of an unknown number of columns that contains of a headline, a description and a button.
Per default every element takes as much space as it's content uses

[image: Unaligned elements]

but the elements should all be aligned. So all headlines, descriptions and buttons should begin at the same height.

[image: Aligned elements]

I have the feeling that flexbox might not help here but a CSS grid might or maybe using `display: table` and turn everything in such structures but sadly I cannot get it to work.

The current markup looks like this

```html
<ul>
  <li class="columns large-4 small-12 medium-4 s-pb-30">
    <h3>Some headline</h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Nostrum facilis praesentium quaerat,
        laboriosam ratione eos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum facilis
        praesentium quaerat, laboriosam ratione eos. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Nostrum facilis praesentium quaerat, laboriosam
        ratione eos.
      </p>
      <a class="button btn-styled center-block--btn" href="/">Foo</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="columns large-4 small-12 medium-4 s-pb-30">
    <h3>Another headline</h3>
    <div>
      <p style="height: 360px;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Nostrum facilis praesentium quaerat,
        laboriosam ratione eos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum facilis
        praesentium quaerat, laboriosam ratione eos.
      </p>
      <a class="button btn-styled center-block--btn" href="/">Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
        Bar Bar </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="columns large-4 small-12 medium-4 s-pb-0">
    <h3 class="title">Surprisingly here's a third headline that should be aligned with the other two</h3>
    <div>
      <p style="height: 360px;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Nostrum facilis praesentium quaerat,
        laboriosam ratione eos.
      </p>
      <a class="button btn-styled center-block--btn" href="/">Baz</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I change your code into a snippet please add css/framework

Comment: You can use CSS grid, but that will require you to change your markup a little, as CSS sub grid is still experimental and poorly supported. Basically each item will have to be siblings in the grid: the heading, the text, and the button, without them being nested inside an `<li>` element. The question is: are you willing to change the markup?

Comment: @Terry yes, I'm willing to change the markup.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini a solution that works independent from a framework would be great.

Comment: @alexanderadam That's great: with that flexibility you can easily achieve what you want using CSS grid: see my answer for a proof-of-concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an implicit CSS grid and then simply use [`grid-auto-flow: column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) so that the grid fills itself up column-first (instead of row-first as per default behaviour).

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
grid-auto-flow: column;
```

Remember that `1fr` is greedy while `auto` is not, so we allow the middle row (where your `<p>` tags are) to grow as much as possible.

This however requires you to "unpack" your individual `<li>` content so that all elements in the grid are siblings of each other, due to the lack of support for CSS subgrid in most browsers at the time of writing.

For the button, you can simply use [`fit-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content) for both `width` and `height` to ensure that it "shrink-wrap" its content, and use `margin: 0 auto` to center it horizontally inside the grid.

See proof-of-concept below:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid a {
  display: block;
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100vh;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <h3>Some headline</h3>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum facilis praesentium quaerat, laboriosam ratione eos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum facilis praesentium quaerat, laboriosam ratione eos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum facilis praesentium quaerat, laboriosam ratione eos.
  </p>
  <a href="/">Foo</a>

  <h3>Another headline</h3>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum facilis praesentium quaerat, laboriosam ratione eos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum facilis praesentium quaerat, laboriosam ratione eos.
  </p>
  <a href="/">Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>

  <h3 class="title">Surprisingly here's a third headline that should be aligned with the other two</h3>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum facilis praesentium quaerat, laboriosam ratione eos.
  </p>
  <a href="/">Baz</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the fast solution. Would this still somehow work if each column would be encapsulated by a separate element so that they could be tackled differently at certain resolutions?